# Git Temporary Commits

Tags: git, workflow, branch, commit, temporary

I'm using Git for tracking history of my project. I have a master branch which tracks release versions and a develop branch where I do all the development. I want to create another branch from develop say feature where I want to track intermediate/temporary commits during feature development. Once the feature development is complete I want to merge it back into development but I don't want all the intermediate/temporary commits from feature branch into development, I just want the final commit from feature into development and discard intermediate/temporary commits from feature branch.

Can you please suggest if this is a good approach? and how to accomplish this. Please suggest if you have and alternative workflow recommendations.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is do an interactive rebase when you are ready to merge back into master. This lets you go back through your commit history and clean up your commits, or in your case, squash them all into one.

```
git rebase -i
```

Here is a very good introduction to this.

> "Interactive rebasing gives you complete control over what your
>   project history looks like. This affords a lot of freedom to
>   developers, as it lets them commit a “messy” history while they’re
>   focused on writing code, then go back and clean it up after the fact"

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase-i/

Comment: This seems like exactly what I want. Thank you. When I try to rebase I'm getting merge conflicts, trying to understand how to resolve this. any suggestions? -- Thank you

Comment: Tough to say without knowing the conflict, they are all unique. Git usually does a good job spelling out the source of the trouble though.